# Conflicting iOS Token Storage Information - Which is it?

Tags: ios, box-api

Where and for how long are the tokens held when using the iOS Box SDK? Are they placed into a keychain or elsewhere?

I found the following line in the "OneCloud on iOS" web page under the "Web API Library" section.

> "Second, the web API Library uses Keychain to store sensitive
>   information such as the Auth Token."

That seems to conflict with following on the "Authentication in your iOS app" web page.

> "The user is now fully logged in and you can use this auth token with
>   every API call that requires it. You may store the authentication
>   token for future use, so that the user does not need to
>   re-authenticate with your application every time they use it. Please
>   use the Keychain (of the Security framework) for this."

Comment: Where do you see the conflict? Both paragraphs propose the usage of Keychain to store the token.

Comment: The first says the keychain is used. The second suggests I as the developer need to setup a keychain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first page you're referring to refers to when you're using our iOS SDK.

The second page you're referring to refers to when you're building your own API integration from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. So I am storing the token into a keychain. I appreciate the confirmation.